# Where can I find math plans for US primary / secondary education?

Tags: education

I'd really like to have an overview of how math is being studied in US. I would love to see how it compares to primary / secondary education in Europe (ex Yugoslav countries).

TIA

Comment: Well, there's arithmetic, general problem solving, then algebra/geometry/calculus.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was looking a more detailed stuff though... For example, I would like to know if there are some sites with actual tests, so I can see what kind of problems they are solving etc. I know this is a little tricky, since I know it's not easy to find for my country, either.

Comment: OH... I found this in 'related'... http://www.corestandards.org/the-standards - it sounds like something I needed...

Comment: Having spent my childhood in Texas public education, [this site](http://www.tea.state.tx.us/student.assessment/taks/released-tests/archive/) comes to mind immediately. If you browse around, you can see tests for 3rd year through 11th (12th) year students (i.e. kids aged 8 - 18)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the U.S., precollege education is not nearly as centeralized as it is in many other countries, so something like the following google search is probably more helpful than trying to look for some type of U.S. national standard:

http://www.google.com/search?q=math+%22state+standards%22+grade

Comment: :) exactly what i was typing below :)... well, first google result was exactly what i found here on math.stackexchange. Thank you very much, it totally answers my question.

Answer (score 3):

Someone from University of Puget Sound wrote a paper check http://www2.ups.edu/faculty/woodward/Mathematics%20Education%20in%20the%20United%20States.pdf
Also check this paper http://www.nctm.org/uploadedFiles/About_NCTM/Corresponding_Societies/MathEdUS2008-Dossey.pdf

And one final link http://www.csun.edu/~vcmth00m/AHistory.html

These are all copyright materials.  You should contact Prof. David Klein from California State University if you are working on such topic.

Comment: Thank you very much Kirthi. I need it for reference only and won't be republishing or anything alike.

Answer (score 2):

Unless someone else gives a better answer, I'll select this one:
Among answers to this question [What should the high school math curriculum consist of?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3087/what-should-the-high-school-math-curriculum-consist-of), I found a great link with correct answer to my questions: http://www.corestandards.org/the-standards

This basically does it. Sweet.