# What is the probability of choosing a interval B such that B is inside the interval A?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $I = [0,\ n],\ A = [a,\ b] : A \subseteq I$

Also, $0 \leq a \leq b \leq n$ and $a, b, n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I'll choose a real value $x$ uniformly out of $I$. What is the probability of the interval $B = [x, x + L]$ be completely inside the interval $A$, i.e $B \subseteq A$? $L$ is a given constant.

$x \in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0},\ 0 \leq x \leq \ n$,

$\ L \in \mathbb{N},\ 0 < L \leq N$.

Comment: Think about it geometrically. What is the maximal value x can have such that still fits still into $A$? Now use the property that you have to choose x uniformly.

Comment: By the way: What do you mean with uniformly? Out of what interval?

Comment: It can't be over all $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$: See this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14777/why-isnt-there-a-uniform-probability-distribution-over-the-positive-real-number#14779

Comment: What is the distribution on $(x,L)$?

Comment: You need to define the distribution of $L$, it has no sense if it is uniformly distributed on $N$

Comment: @Quasar Hey, sorry for that! I updated the question answering your comment. By uniformly I mean that every value of $I$ have an equal probability of being chosen. Is that an enough answer? My math is not good.

Comment: @DjuraMarinkov hey, L is a given constant, a natural number less or equal than $N$. Is that enough?

Comment: yes it is, $p=\frac{b-a-L}{n}$ if $L<b-a$ otherwise is 0

Comment: @DjuraMarinkov thanks! That makes a lot of sense, can you explain your intuition on that result please?