# Paradox of a set being twice as big as another one

Tags: probability, logic, paradoxes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Card doubling paradox](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234/card-doubling-paradox)

I don't know how to resolve the following paradoxon: Assume two finite sets *A, B*, one being twice as big than the other, but you don't know which. You want to guess the bigger one. You want to choose *A*, but before that, you reason like this: "With probability 0.5 the other set *B* has half as many elements as *A*, and with probability 0.5 it has twice as many, so *B*'s expected size is 1.25 |*A*|, so I should choose *B*."

> What's the mistake in this line of
>   reasoning?

Comment: I think it's because if $A$ and $B$ are already given, the probability that $B$ has twice as many elements or half as many elements of $A$ is either $1$ or $0$ since it's already determined.

Comment: Can this really be all that is to say?

Comment: The problem (from my view) is that you're assuming there exists a well-defined probability distribution on the set of possible sizes of $A$ and $B$ satisfying certain properties, and this is false. This is known as the two envelopes problem; see the question I've closed this question as a duplicate of or the Wikipedia article for details. The related discussion at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9037/how-is-it-that-you-can-guess-if-one-of-a-pair-of-random-numbers-is-larger-with-p might also be helpful.

Comment: @Qiaochu: Should I delete my question, what would you give as an advice?

Comment: we generally don't delete duplicates. I think it's good to have more search terms pointing to the same question.