# Conditional probability that standard gaussian random variable is larger than another

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Say there are two standard Gaussian random variables $X$ and $Y$. I am trying to evaluate the probability that the larger of the two is selected, given that it is known whether $X$ is positive or negative (the strategy is selecting $X$ if $X$ is positive and selecting $Y$ if $X$ is negative). In equation form this is
$$Pr(X-Y>0|X>0) + Pr(X-Y<0|X<0)$$

How can this expression be evaluated? Numerically it appears to be $\frac{3}{4}$, and intuitively this makes sense.

I am also interested in this probability in the more general case, where the strategy involves selecting $X$ if $X-S>0$ and $Y$ otherwise, where $S$ is another independent Gaussian random variable.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Did you mean $\text{Pr}(X-Y>0|X>0)\text{Pr}(X>0)+\text{Pr}(X-Y<0|X<0)\text{Pr}(X<0)$?

Comment: Yes, that's right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following assumes $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

As Angela Richardson pointed out, you probably actually want to compute
$$P(X-Y > 0 \mid X > 0) P(X>0) + P(X-Y <0 \mid X<  0) P(X<0)$$
which is $3/4$. (The quantity in your post is not $3/4$.)

---

For the first term, it suffices to compute $P(X-Y > 0, X>0)$. (Why?)

Consider the region of the plane that contains $(x,y)$ pairs satisfying $x-y>0$ and $x>0$. Then use rotational symmetry of the vector $(X,Y)$ to compute the probability.

The other term can be handled similarly.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to evaluate the more general case as well? I'm guessing symmetry no longer holds once $S$ is introduced.

Comment: In case anyone is curious, the stackexchange post in this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655972/help-rules-of-a-game-whose-details-i-dont-remember/656426#656426) gives the solution as to how to compute the more general case. When $S$ is the standard normal, the probability turns out to be exactly $\frac{2}{3}$, and approaches $\frac{3}{4}$ as the variance of $S$ approaches $0$.