# What are some good subtly incorrect proofs of obviously incorrect results?

Tags: big-list, fake-proofs

I'm interested in compiling a list of proofs that *look* logically correct at a glance, but "prove" something obviously incorrect.  Here are some examples.

1. - $e^{i \pi} = -1$
   - $e^{2i\pi} = 1$
   - $2i\pi = \ln 1$
   - $2i\pi = 0$
   - $-4\pi^2 = 0$
2. Let $a = b$.  Then:

   - $a = b$
   - $a^2 = ab$
   - $a^2 - b^2 = ab - b^2$
   - $(a+b)(a-b) = b(a-b)$
   - $a + b = b$
   - $a = 0$
3. The [Two Envelopes Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-envelope_paradox):

> You are on a game show, in which the host fills two indistinguishable envelopes with random amounts of money, such that one envelope contains $x$ dollars and the other contains $10x$ dollars.  You pick an envelope at random, but then you are offered a chance to switch envelopes (intuitively, it shouldn't matter whether or not you choose to switch).  You reason: there is a 50/50 chance that I currently hold the higher-valued or lower-valued envelope in my hands.  If I keep this envelope, my expected return is $x$.  If I switch, then my expected return is $\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{10}x) + \frac{1}{2}(10x) = 5.05x$.  Therefore, I should switch.

Any other good ones?

Comment: Also: should I have made this a community wiki post, since it asks for a big list but doesn't have a single definite "acceptable" answer?

Comment: Also, [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113/what-are-some-classic-fallacious-proofs?rq=1) is a possible repeat, but it didn't gain too much traction.

Comment: Yes, you should have made it CW.  I don't think the first two are examples of "subtly incorrect" proofs, because the basic error is not subtle at all. Both start from $f(x) = f(y)$  for some noninjective $f$, and then conclude $x=y$, and there are probably dozens of examples of this error in the folklore and on this web site.

Comment: Also if you are going to claim that your question is different from [What are some classic fallacious proofs?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113/what-are-some-classic-fallacious-proofs?rq=1), you should find at least one example that is not given there.

Comment: @MJD: I didn't find the repeat thread until after I posted this one, so the repeat examples are a coincidence (maybe there just aren't that many good fallacious proofs floating around).  But either way, #1 is not a repeat.  In terms of "too subtle," I planned to use these on advanced-math high schoolers, not career mathematicians.  Treat the subtlety of the examples as a guideline for Minimum Required Subtlety.

Comment: The $f(x) = f(y)\implies x=y$ error is all over the questions in the [tag:fake-proofs] tag. One perennially popular error is to write $1^2 = (-1)^2$ and conclude $1=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's [one](http://math.mit.edu/~tchow/mathstuff/proof.pdf) mentioned by the logician/mathematician Timothy Chow. It's a "proof" that $0 = 1$ using something more interesting than the usual division-by-zero tricks; specifically it's a "proof" via advanced calculus, involving a differentiation under the integral sign.

Comment: Answers on this site are supposed to be self-contained.  You should at least provide a summary.

Comment: Very well; I've given a brief summary. I'm not completely familiar with the culture here; at MathOverflow, the way I had answered initially would be considered acceptable.