# "A two-envelopes puzzle"

Tags: probability, paradoxes

This is Problem 1.25 from Tsitsiklis, Bertsekas, Introduction to Probability, 2nd edition.

> You are handed two envelopes, and you know that each contains a
>   positive integer dollar amount and that the two amounts are different.
>   The values of these two amounts are modeled as constants that are
>   unknown. Without knowing what the amounts are, you select at random
>   one of the two envelopes, and after looking at the amount inside, you
>   may switch envelopes if you wish. A friend claims that the following
>   strategy will increase above $1/2$ your probability of ending up with
>   the envelope with the larger amount:
>
> Toss a coin repeatedly. Let  $X$  be equal to $1/2$ plus the number of
>   tosses required to obtain heads for the first time, and switch if the
>   amount in the envelope you selected is less than the value of  $X$ . 
>   Is your friend correct?

The answer given in the solution manual claims that this indeed helps, and that the probability of getting the better envelope is given by $$p = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} P(B)$$

where $B$ is the event that $a<X<b$, with $a,b$ being the smaller and larger amount of dollars, respectively.

I do not buy this solution for the following reason: tossing a coin has nothing to do with the contents of the envelopes. You do not gain any information by doing it. You could just as well count the amount of leaves on a nearby tree instead and use that for $X$.

Similarly, opening the first envelope also gives you no useful information about the ordering relation between $a$ and $b$, so surely that's another red herring. Even if you forget the coin tossing, the probability of "winning" is still $1/2$, swap or no swap.

I suppose maybe the catch is in interpreting the following sentence: "The values of these two amounts are modeled as constants that are unknown". I take it to mean that they're just two randomly and independently generated numbers.

Am I out of my mind? Surely the solution manual is wrong.

Comment: Well... they can't be independently generated since they aren't allowed to be equal.  Regardless, I agree with the book's solution.  Make yourself a tree diagram and remember that your original selection is equally likely to be the larger envelope as it is the smaller envelope and recognize that the chance to swap is different for each.

Comment: [This wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_envelopes_problem) should provide a good deal more information to a slightly altered problem.  The main point to take away from it is that the chance to switch is *dependent* (*not independent*) on the amount of money in the envelope you looked in.  "*Tossing a coin has nothing to do with the contents of the envelopes*" but answering whether you tossed more times than the amount in the envelope *does* have something to do with the contents.

Comment: I've seen this one where the person handing you the envelopes is an intelligent adversary who knows the algorithm you are going to use and is permitted to manipulate the numbers and the order of the envelopes to try to cause you as much trouble as possible.  The technique still works.

Comment: The only reason why counting the leaves on a nearby tree might not work just as well as the coin tossing is if we think it is possible that there is some number $N$ such that the amount in either envelope can never be less than $N$ but the tree cannot have $N$ or more leaves. In that case the answer doesn't work. The advantage of coin tossing is there is no $N$ such that the number of tosses cannot be $N$ or more.

Comment: @JMoravitz: I think this is actually closer to the dowry problem than the two-envelopes problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem

Comment: The main problem I have with this formulation that it implicitly assumes that "your probability of ending up with the envelope with the larger amount" is something that can be defined. In this problem statement it cannot, since there is no probability distribution. As a reality check, I ask: so if the probability is larger than $0.5$, how much larger is it? There is no way to tell. All you can say is that if some probability distribution were chosen, then the probability (would be defined, and) would always turn out to be larger than $0.5$.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The manual is right.  The coin flips just generate the number $X$.  If both envelopes contain numbers smaller than $X$, you have a random choice among the envelopes because you will take the second one.  If both envelopes contain numbers greater than $X$, you have a random choice because you will take the first one.  If one is greater than $X$ and the other is less, you will certainly pick the correct one, so if there is any probability this situation obtains you have a strictly greater than $\frac 12$ chance of picking the correct envelope.  You can generate $X$ any way you want with the same effect as long as it has positive probability to be in each interval $(k,k+1)$.  The argument tacitly assumes that it is possible one is below $X$ and one is above $X$.  The reason to do the coin flipping is to get a distribution where all naturals plus $\frac 12$ have some chance to be chosen.  This guarantees that there is some chance $X$ is between the two numbers.

Comment: I think you can "generate $X$ any way you want" just as long as the support of the distribution of $X$ is enough to justify the assumption that one number could be below $X$ and the other above $X$. The coin tosses give a support that includes $n+\frac12$ for every positive integer $n,$ which is sufficient. I believe it is OK for the support to have larger gaps than that, but not for it to be bounded.

Comment: @DavidK:  if it has larger gaps than that and the person filling the envelopes knows your strategy he can leave you with just a $\frac 12$ chance.  If there is no chance $2 \lt X \lt 3$ he could put $2$ and $3$ in the envelopes.  A bounded distribution works the same way.  He could just put two numbers above the bound.

Comment: My mistake was that I thought this was the two-envelope problem in which one envelope contains twice as much money as the other. Re-reading the question, I see that the amounts are merely required to be two different integers, so the support of $X$ must include one number between each pair of positive integers.

Comment: @DavidK: I have added a bit to clarify.  Thanks.

Comment: Does the result rely on any assumptions about the distribution of $a,b$?

Comment: @anonuser01:  no, it does not except to rely on the fact that they are different, which we are given.  We just need a positive probability of generating a number between any pair of positive integers.

Comment: I tried to derive the $p = 0.5 + 0.5P(B)$ in the expression, but I'm not getting it. If you apply the law of total probability, and condition on the disjoint events of 
$\{a > X = x \}, \{b < X  = x\}, \{a < X = x < b\}$, you get
$$
p = Pr(W|e_1) * Pr(e_1) + Pr(W|e_2)* Pr(e_2) + Pr(W|e_3)∗ Pr(e_3) \\
= 0.5( Pr (e_2) + Pr(e_2)) + 0.5 * P(B) \\
\text{since } P(B) = Pr(e_3) \ \text{and } Pr(W|e_1) = Pr(W|e_2) = Pr(W|e_3) = 0.5
$$.

If we compare this with the first expression, it would suggest that $Pr(e_1) + Pr(e_2) = 1$, which is wrong. Did I do something wrong here?

Comment: @anonuser01:  The point is that if $X \lt a$ or $X \gt b$ you are making a random selection.  If $a \lt X \lt b$ you are sure to get the right one.  Your probability of winning is $\frac 12$ for a random pick plus the extra $\frac 12P(B)$ if you are in the interval where you are guaranteed to win.  You have a typo in the second line where the first $e_2$ should be $e_1$ and in the third line we have $Pr(W|e_3)=1$

Comment: Oh wait a second, the $Pr(W | e_3) = 0.5$ that I have was actually not a typo. It was an incorrect thought thought process that I had. So accounting for that, I now get the right expression. But I'm having trouble seeing how $0.5$ is associated with a random pick. From my expression above, I can easily see that $0.5(Pr(e_1) + Pr(e_2)$ is associated with the random pick, which is $0.5P(B)$ short of $0.5$. How is half of the $P(B)$, associated with the $e_3$ event, associated with a random pick?

Comment: I know that half of $P(B)$ is associated with us having initially having picked the $a$ envelope, and hence we switch to the $b$ envelope, and the other half is associated with us having initially picked the $b$ envelope, and hence we don't switch. But I'm not sure how either of these would be affiliated with a "random pick."

Comment: I think the best way to think about it is  what I said last comment.  If $X$ is outside $(a,b)$ you make a random selection and win with probability $\frac 12$.  If $X$ is inside you win all the time.  The $0.5+0.5P(B)$ spends half of the $1$ for being inside to complete the leading $0.5$, then has $0.5P(B)$ left over so shows that.

Answer (score 8):

Actually it seems logical to me.

The chance that you will change is larger for the wrong envelope.

Comment: This is a good way to understand the result. Any algorithm that results in a higher probability that you will change envelopes if you have the envelope with the smaller amount in it will increase your expected return.

Answer (score 4):

So long as $X$ has a positive probability of being between the values in the two envelopes, it can help improve your decision making, by slightly biasing your decision upwards in the way indicated.

The coin toss version works since it has a positive probability of being in each gap between positive integers, no matter what are the distributions of the amounts in the two envelopes.

Your leaves on the tree idea might or might not help, as it runs the risk of being too high (you can already see there are lots of leaves, perhaps well in excess of the amounts in the envelopes) or of being too small (there is a limit to the the number of leaves), depending on the distributions of the amounts in the envelopes and of leaves on the tree.  And you do not know those distributions.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/965855) deals with a different two-envelope problem: the amount in one envelope is always double the amount in the other envelope. However, we can evaluate the strategy given in the solution manual  in the same way that the strategy given in that answer was evaluated.

---

Let $P(a,b)$ be the probability that the lower amount is $a$ and the larger amount is $b$. Then
$$
\sum_{1\le a\lt b}P(a,b)=1\tag1
$$
Picking an envelope at random, the expected value is
$$
E=\sum_{1\le a\lt b}\frac{a+b}2P(a,b)\tag2
$$

---

Pick some $k$ and switch when the amount seen is less than $k+\frac12$. When $a\le k\lt b$, the expectation is $b$ instead of $\frac{a+b}2$; that is, an excess of $\frac{b-a}2$. This strategy increases the expected value by
$$
\begin{align}
\Delta(k)
&=\sum_{1\le a\le k\lt b}\frac{b-a}2P(a,b)\\[3pt]
&\ge0\tag3
\end{align}
$$

---

If $P(a,b)=0$ when $a\le k\lt b$, then the strategy above does not help, but it does not hurt; that is, $\Delta(k)=0$. To guarantee an increase, we employ coin tosses. $(1)$ implies that for some $a\lt b$, we must have $P(a,b)\gt0$, and then for $a\le k\lt b$, $\Delta(k)\gt0$.

The probability that it takes $k$ tosses to obtain heads is $2^{-k}$. Therefore, by employing the coin tosses, we get an expected increase of
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty2^{-k}\Delta(k)\gt0\tag4
$$
That is, the expected value increases.

Comment: If the amounts in the envelopes are chosen by the same coin tossing algorithm, then $P(a,b)=\frac{3\,[0\lt a\lt b]}{2^{a+b}}$, and this strategy raises the expected value from $\frac73$ to $3$, which is pretty good since the average high envelope is $\frac{10}3$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the other posts are correct when they say the solution manual is correct.

To address the other concerns about the tossing of a coin having nothing to do with the contents of the envelopes etc, I can offer this:

In the question, the friend suggests coin flipping. Instead of the coin flipping scenario, he could have suggested that if you get an envelope with one dollar in it, then change envelopes. This is always correct and will increase above 1/2 your probability of ending up with the envelope with the larger amount. I think this is all the coin tossing does.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a technicality that explains why the coin toss method always works while choosing the number of leaves on a tree or always trading if your envelope contains one dollar won't necessarily work:

The amounts in the envelopes are taken from some unspecified range of numbers. Note that any number chosen within that range will increase the probability of winning.

The coin toss can, with some probability >0, choose a number in any possible range. Therefore, it always works.

The problem with choosing the number of leaves on a tree, or always trading when your envelope contains one dollar, or choosing a number using a variety of other methods, is that it doesn't guarantee that the number chosen will fall within the range that the amounts in the envelopes are taken from.

For example, if the chosen tree has 3,000 leaves and the range from which the amounts in the envelope are taken is from 4,000 to 100,000, then neither choosing the number of leaves nor trading when your envelope has one dollar will improve your chance of winning.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with you @Spine Feast. Those lines in the solution manual applying the total probability theorem are not right.
For example, it says

> P(W|A) = $\frac{1}{2}$(P(W|notA) + P(W|A))

The above implies that P(A) = P(notA) = 1/2. The same logic applies for P(W|C), so

> P(C) = P(notC) = 1/2.

With both equations above, and P(A) + P(B) + P(C) = 1, then

> P(B) = 0

so

> P(W) = 1/2

Which means no improvement at all!

The solution manual has fallen for the fallacy here!!!

Comment: What are A,B, C, W here?